# std_msgs/UInt16.msg is not a legal message field type

Tags: cmake, ros

I'm trying to implement a PckPlace ros service, but I get the this error:

```
/opt/ros/noetic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em:56: 
error: <class 'genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec'>: 
std_msgs/UInt16.msg is not a legal message field type
```

#### PickPlace.srv

```
std_msgs/UInt16.msg speed
---
bool success
```

#### Package.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>pick_place</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The package</description>

  <maintainer email="s@s.com">s</maintainer>

  <license>LGPLv2.1</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>

  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>

  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>

  <depend>rospy_message_converter</depend>
  <depend>message_generation</depend>
  <depend>message_runtime</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>

</package>
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(pick_place)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  rospy_message_converter
  message_generation
)

catkin_python_setup()

# Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
  FILES
  PickPlace.srv
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

# Declare catkin package
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  rospy
  rospy_message_converter
  std_msgs
  message_runtime
  # LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
)

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
  # nodes/pp_client.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Can you please tell me how can I resolve this error? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the tutorial on [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). The tutorial describes how to define custom message types.

To sum it up:

- [Built in types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) can be used straight forward like `string`, `int64`, ...
- Specific message types can be used by combing their package and name like `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance`, ...

Since your message type uses built in types, it needs to be defined like this:

```
uint16 speed
---
bool success
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was generated by the wrong message type, inside the .Srv the extention `.msg` is not necessary and moreover generates an error!